# Displaying hidden content with onClick event in html with css and js

Tags: javascript, html, css

At first I wanted to hide all the body and show only one image, but it seems that it's not possible since hiding the body with display:none would hide all of it's children. So I changed my code to just hiding the parameters I want to hide.

At Bottom line: I want to show the hidden content when I click on the content that is not hidden.

Here is my HTML Code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1wYH.png)
 js code is 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Rskc.png)
And finally  css code is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCcjA.png)

Even the code looks very simple but i'm struggling: when I click on the image, nothing happens.

I'm absolutely sorry if my question is not very well formulated, this is my first question on stackoverflow and I will be glad to make it more clear. 
Thank in advance.

Comment: please add the code in **text form** to the question. you may use the power of `<>`, where you get a small IDE.

Comment: You are using `.style.display=block`, that should be the string `"block"`, the quotes are important. (Your code as it is should be throwing an error, always look in the console when things don't work as expected.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your support!
I've actually found the answer. I was facing some problems with getElementsByTagName and getElementsByClassName since you actually had to use the for loop to display all of the elements. So I just used getElementById and used the "onclick" event in the HTML code.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in JS, you have to use quotations marks.

... `.style.display = "block";`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        p {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>This is some random text</p>
    <img id="click" src="" width="500px" height="500px">

    <script>
        var toggle = document.getElementById("click");
        toggle.addEventListener("click", show);

        function show() {
            var p = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].style.display = "block";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```